# Login window won't show up

Tags: python, tkinter, window, self

If I run my code there are no errors, but also the window won't show up. Does anyone see my mistake?
I searched for mistakes I could have made but I didn't find them.

```
from tkinter import *

class Login:
    def __int__(self):
        self.user ={'Hello':'123'}
        self.loginwindow = Tk()
        self.loginwindow.geometry("500x300")
        self.loginwindow.resizable(width= False, height= False)


        self.loginlabel = Label(text="Login",font= ("arial",50))
        self.loginausgabe = Label(self.loginwindow)
        self.loginusernamelabel = Label(self.loginwindow, text="Username",font= ("arial",12))
        self.loginusernameentry = Entry(self.loginwindow,font= ("arial",12))
        self.loginpasswordlabel = Label(self.loginwindow,text="Password",font= ("arial",12))
        self.loginpasswordentry = Entry(self.loginwindow,font= ("arial",12), show="*")
        self.loginbtn = Button(self.loginwindow,text="login",width= 38, command=self.Login)


        self.loginlabel.place(x="140",y="0")
        self.loginausgabe.place(x="140",y="140")
        self.loginusernamelabel.place(x="140",y ="80")
        self.loginusernameentry.place(x="230",y="80")
        self.loginpasswordlabel.place(x="140",y ="100")
        self.loginpasswordentry.place(x="230",y="100")
        self.loginbtn.place(x="140",y="120")
        self.loginwindow.mainloop()


    def Login(self):
        loginusernameentry = self.loginusernameentry.get()
        if loginusernameentry in self.user.keys():
            if self.loginpasswordlabel.get() == self.user[loginusernameentry]:
                self.loginausgabe.config(text="Welcome!")
            else: self.loginausgabe.config(text="Invalid password!")
        else: self.loginausgabe.config(text="Unknown User!")
        self.loginusernameentry.config(text="")
        self.loginusernameentry.config(text="")


l = Login()
```

Comment: Try inheriting directly from `Tk` with your `Login` class: `class Login(Tk)`, then replace any references to `self.loginwindow` with just `self`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it didn't change anything. Do you have further suggestions you'd like to share with me?

Comment: I'm not sure offhand. There's some risk that your `Login` class having a member method that's *also* called `Login` could cause conflicts. It's better to name the method something else, and typically starting with a lowercase letter: `usr_login`, but I don't think that's what the issue is here.

Comment: [An example](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html#coupling-widget-variables) from the documentation. Try moving Tk and mainloop outside of your class.

Comment: Typo: `__int__` should be `__init__`.  As other said, better not calling `mainloop()` inside `__init__()`.

Comment: Thanks to you all. It now works. I didn't see that I wrote" __int__" instead of "__init__"